# How to convert CoreData Date to DateTime in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsdate

I have `CoreData` myDate = date, Entity column and returns output:

```
let mydate = coreDataValues[0].myDate!
print(mydate)

OUTPUT == 2017-02-01 12:45:40 +0000
```

I want to convert `mydate` to `datetime` under below like , example ;

```
2017-12-20-23-59-59
```

How can I do it ?

Ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
var date = dateFormatter.string(from: mydate as Date)
print(date)
```

> OUTPUT = 2017-02-01-18-10-01